# Twilio ios client app pass parameters to server so that new member is added to conference

Tags: php, ios, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I understand that Twilio conference call is a way for multiple people to connect to the same session.

Once in a connected conference call where there is an agent, and multiple clients through a iOS app as a Twilio client connected with a capability token they want to add more people.

Let's say that in 14:00h, `agent` and `client1` have connected to a conference call friendly_named `Conference1`.

While in this conference, `client1` with his iOS app, presses the + button to add a new client (`client2`). Then selects from a list of phone number +123456789, or types the phone number +123456789 and the person with phone number +123456789 is connected to the conference call by my server.

I know how to add a new person to a conference call, that is I have made the server PHP code to connect a phone number and add him to the conference call.

> $client->account->calls->create("twilio number", +123456789, ...)

But how can an iOS client app pass this parameters (`phoneNumber`, `friendlyConfName`) while in a call with an agent, to my server so I can handle it (that is call the `client2`)?

I can maybe have a route/addMember where the iOS client passes the number/s.

I'm asking about the iOS applications side: how can the iOS pass parameters to my server while in a call with Twilio number (agent)?

Add new member to conference call

[image: Add new member to conference call]